# How to send an image from Android to a WCF server?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, multipartform-data

I working on sending an image from Android to a WCF server. I tried sending the FileBOdy in a multi-part body, but that didn't get the job done. Finally I tried sending a ByteArrayBody in a multi-part body. It did work, but I got a corrupted image in server. I googled a lot, but couldn't get an acceptable solution to my problem. Can any one spot a mistake in my Android or WCF code?

**Android code**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

// Making HTTP request
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String URL1 = "http://rohit-pc:8078/service1.svc/UploadImage";

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL1);

    ContentBody bin = null;
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");

    reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
    reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));

    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String sResponse;
     s = new StringBuilder();

    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        s = s.append(sResponse);
    }
    System.out.println("Response: " + s);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
}
```

**WCF code**

```
public string GetStream(Stream str,string filename) {

        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string Path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images");
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Path + "/" +filename, FileMode.Create);

        byte[] bytearray = new byte[100000000];

        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
        do {
            bytesRead = str.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > 0);

        file.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
        file.Close();
        file.Dispose();

       return "Success";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use Base64 format to send the image encoded in base64 format as string.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer an old question. But I had spent over 5 hours to figure out the issue. So would like to share the solution I found. **My issue was a corrupted image saved in the server**.

Actually, WCF does not have an effective way of parsing the multipart form data. Thats why the suggestion from MS is to use the raw stream to transmit images to wcf services.

So after a few hours of struggling to get rid of MultipartEntity(replaced with ByteArrayEntity), I finally got it working by using the below code. Hope this should help some one.

### Android

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0]);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);

byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
// the below is the important one, notice no multipart here just the raw image data 
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));
```

then the rest of the actual http client continues.

### Wcf Interface

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
     ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate:="/UploadPhoto?UsedCarID={UsedCarID}&FileName={FileName}")>
Sub UploadPhoto(UsedCarID As Integer, FileName As String, FileContents As Stream)
```

This is my first post at Stack Overflow thank you so much.